# How to get list of tags from a set of images in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, images, photos, tags

Title pretty much says it all. I have a folder filled with many images and it would be handy to get a list of all the tags that are used so that when I'm adding new images I can reference that list to make sure I don't miss a tag that would be applicable. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Live Photo Gallery from [Windows Live Essentials](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-essentials) seems to do the job.

See the article [Working with digital pictures](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Working-with-digital-pictures).

[image]

Some more possible (free) products are :

[JB Music Catalogue](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/File-CD-DVD-Catalog/JB-Music-Catalogue.shtml)
[Best Music Library Organizer](http://www.bestorganizer.net/best-music-library-organizer.html)
[TagScanner](http://www.xdlab.ru/en/index.htm)